# Fetch data from website getting error: existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host c#

Tags: c#, multithreading, http-post

I have gotten error an error on the production server at some time (9 AM to 2 PM) , but not on the test server.
Actually, I have scrap data fromdifferent websites using http request.
It's run daily every hour

Error :

```
System.Net.WebException: The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a send. 
---> System.IO.IOException: Unable to read data from the transport connection: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host. 
---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host
```

CODE :

```
HttpWebRequest webRequest = WebRequest.Create(URL) as HttpWebRequest;
webRequest.CookieContainer = cookies; 
StreamReader responseReader = new StreamReader(webRequest.GetResponse().GetResponseStream()); 
HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)webRequest.GetResponse(); 
response.Cookies = webRequest.CookieContainer.GetCookies(webRequest.RequestUri); 
string responseData = responseReader.ReadToEnd(); 
responseReader.Close();
webRequest.KeepAlive = false; 
return responseData;
```

Comment: can you please add your code

Comment: HttpWebRequest webRequest = WebRequest.Create(URL) as HttpWebRequest;                                             webRequest.CookieContainer = cookies;        
            StreamReader responseReader = new StreamReader(webRequest.GetResponse().GetResponseStream());
            HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)webRequest.GetResponse();
            response.Cookies = webRequest.CookieContainer.GetCookies(webRequest.RequestUri);
            string responseData = responseReader.ReadToEnd();
            responseReader.Close();webRequest.KeepAlive = false;        return responseData;

Answer (score 0):

try with adding following lines in your code

```
ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = new System.Net.Security.RemoteCertificateValidationCallback(AcceptAll);
```

and function will be defined as

```
public bool AcceptAll(object sender, System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate certification, System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Chain chain, System.Net.Security.SslPolicyErrors sslPolicyErrors)
{
    return true;
}
```

Comment: thanks,I am trying to add these line on my logic and see what happen on production server.I inform you ,if its run ;)

Comment: yes ,its working fine on test server but gotten error on production server